# Compiling MongoDB r2.0.2 on ubuntu 10.04 resulted in error

Tags: mongodb, compiler-errors, ubuntu-10.04

I am compiling MongoDB from source with instructions from http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+for+Linux

I ran into this error after ran "scons all":

```
rty/js-1.7/jsscan.c
third_party/js-1.7/jsscan.c:112:22: error: jsautokw.h: No such file or directory
third_party/js-1.7/jsscan.c: In function 'FindKeyword':
third_party/js-1.7/jsscan.c:122: warning: label 'test_guess' defined but not used
third_party/js-1.7/jsscan.c:119: warning: label 'got_match' defined but not used
scons: *** [third_party/js-1.7/jsscan.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors
```

I am on a 64 bit ubuntu 10.04. gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5), scons version is:

```
script: v1.2.0.d20100117.r4629, 2010/01/17 22:23:21, by scons on scons-dev
engine: v1.2.0.d20100117.r4629, 2010/01/17 22:23:21, by scons on scons-dev
```

Does anyone have the same problem? There are similar errors reported for this jsscan file in earlier versions, but has been fixed since.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing on Ubuntu 10.4.3 LTS. The docs say that if we have errors on ubuntu to try building our own spidermonkey via the instructions here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+Spider+Monkey I will try and report back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dude it worked! Do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove xulrunner-1.9.2-dev xulrunner-1.9.2
curl -O ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/js/js-1.7.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf js-1.7.0.tar.gz
cd js/src
export CFLAGS="-DJS_C_STRINGS_ARE_UTF8"
make -f Makefile.ref
sudo JS_DIST=/usr make -f Makefile.ref export
```

Then run `scons all` again

Comment: Also, scream "XUUUUUULL RUNNNNNER" really loud when you uninstall it, just for kicks.

Comment: Cool, thanks Jeff. Accept the answer so other people know this works.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to uninstall "xulrunner-1.9.2-dev" and "xulrunner-1.9.2" as it's also uninstalls other packages you may need later.
Just install the newer version of scons package (I used for it scons-2.1.0).

1. Download [scons-2.1.0.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scons/files/scons/2.1.0/)
2. Install it and use the installed one instead of the scons v1.2.0 repository package for Ubuntu 10.04.

It worked for me without any additional tricks.

Comment: I confirm that upgrading scons is sufficient. In my case, I did the following: `apt-get install python-virtualenv` then `virtualenv ~/env` then `. ~/env/bin/activate` then download scons and `python setup.py install` it (because `pip install scons` did not work for some weird reason). Then the MongoDB finished like a charm.

Comment: I ran into problems using a downloaded version of `scons` while still having the old Ubuntu version installed. Removing the Ubuntu version using `apt-get remove` solved it.